# Método .includes() no funciona -Javascript

Tags: javascript

estoy haciendo una validacion de un array para saber si contiene determinada subcadena, esto lo hago con el metodo `.includes()` de javascript, sin embargo no me funciona me dice que la subcadena no esta contenidad cuando si lo esta

```
//message.content= "-bot -avatar"
let mensaje = message.content.split('-') //esto devuelve el array
//['','bot','avatar']
console.log(mensaje.includes('bot')) //me imprime false
if(mensaje.includes('bot')){
    console.log('bot si esta en el array')
}
```

no se porque pasa esto, me podrian ayudar?

Comment: Puedes mostrar el valor de `message.content`?, si usas `'boT-goo-fa'.split('-').includes('bot')` regresa `false` al igual que expresiones de la forma `'bot - goo-fa'`.

Comment: El valor del segundo elemento de tu `array` es: `bot ` (con un espacio al final). Por favor, revisa bien lo que estás haciendo. Un `array` no contiene *subcadenas*, simplemente contiene *elementos*. Si deseas saber si una cadena contiene una subcadena, aplica directamente [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) sobre la cadena, sin necesidad de convertirla en un `array`. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras ```bot``` no contiene espacio igual en el array esta sin espacio, voy aplicar lo que me dices y vere, gracias

Comment: @MauricioContreras gracias si me sirvio, sin embargo cual es la diferencia con hacerlo con array?, ya que en la documentacion estan esos ejemplos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal como digo en mi [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/441580/m%c3%a9todo-includes-no-funciona-javascript#comment787135_441580):

> El valor del segundo elemento de tu `array` es: `bot`  (con un espacio al final). Por favor, revisa bien lo que estás haciendo. Un `array` no contiene *subcadenas*, simplemente contiene *elementos*. Si deseas saber si una cadena contiene una subcadena, aplica directamente [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) sobre la cadena, sin necesidad de convertirla en un `array`.

Si aún así, deseas usar un `array`, asegúrate de pasar el argumento correcto al método `includes()` de tu `array`. Por ejemplo:

```js
let cadena = "-bot -avatar";
let arr = cadena.split('-'); // esto devuelve el array
                              //['','bot ','avatar']

// veamos el array:
// envolvemos cada elemento entre dobles comillas
arr.forEach(element => {
  console.log(`"${element}", tamaño: ${element.length}`);
});
// el segundo elemento tiene un espacio: 'bot '

console.log("arr.includes('bot'): ", arr.includes('bot'));  // me imprime false
                                       // porque 'bot' !== 'bot '
console.log("'bot' === 'bot ': ",'bot' === 'bot ');

console.log("arr.includes('bot '): ",arr.includes('bot '));  // me imprime true

// ahora usamos includes directamente sobre la cadena
if(cadena.includes('bot')){
    console.log('bot si esta en la cadena');
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Sucede que al usar [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) en tu cadena:

```
"-bot -avatar"
```

Se generan los siguientes elementos:

```
"", "bot ", "avatar"
```

Que corresponden a las subcadenas resultantes de separar la cadena justo donde está el caracter `-`.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema y te de mayor claridad sobre lo que sucede con `split()`.

Comment: esto se podia resolver con ```.trim()``` para quitar los espacios vacios, pero igual gracias